# How to enable Focusrite Scarlett 4i4 Gen3 mixer on Ubuntu Studio 20.04.3

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, interface

I have installed Ubuntu Studio 20.04.3 on my Lenovo Thinkpad W520 with success. It appears to work very well, using the included DAWS as well as others. What a fantastic collaborative project!

I would like to control my very popular **Focusrite Scarlett 4i4 Gen3 audio interface**. Being class compliant, it sorta works, but in order for it to be fully functional, *this device needs software control.*

When I use alsamixer from terminal, I see the audio interface, but when I hit F6 and select it, I get a message that there is no mixer for it. Obviously, the drivers for this functionality do not load or are simply not there.

I attempted to enable the mixer by adding the required driver configuration files I have seen out there in the /etc/modprobe.d folder. I have tried several variants out there without success:

- usb_audio.conf (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zFA5piXf8Q)
- scarlett.conf (https://github.com/Focusrite-Scarlett-on-Linux/sound-usb-kernel-module)

ALSA mixer still gives me the error message: No mixer for this device!

I found this reference for the complete drivers:
https://github.com/Focusrite-Scarlett-on-Linux/sound-usb-kernel-module

However, most of the command lines are rejected in Ubuntu Studio for some reason.

*- Could it be that the instructions are for another distribution?*

*- Perhaps there are slightly different command syntaxes for Ubuntu Studio?*

*- Could it be the drivers are already included but my configuration is wrong?*

I am looking forward to getting this working and I appreciate any form of support.

**Please advise. *Many thanks in advance.***

Paul Isabelle

Answer (score 4):

What to make sure?

- you are on 5.14 or better even 5.16 kernel
- you have in `/etc/modprobe.d/scralett.conf` following line `options snd_usb_audio vid=0x1235 pid=0x8212 device_setup=1`

Reboot with the above to make sure everything gets loaded.

To see if the driver is present and enabled: `dmesg | grep -i -A 5 -B 5 scarlett` should display information like:

```
New USB device found, idVendor=1235, idProduct=8212, bcdDevice= 6.0b
Product: Scarlett 4i4 USB
Focusrite Scarlett Gen 2/3 Mixer Driver enabled pid=0x8212
```

What I found useful was to use a sledgehammer approach `options snd_usb_audio vid=0x1235 pid=0x8212 device_setup=1,1,1,1` to pass that option to the first 4 USB audio devices if you have more then one sound device like USB camera etc.

Very useful source of information: https://linuxmusicians.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=23272

Comment: On 22.04 ... device_setup=1,1,1,1 helped.